# Why does h:link value call bean method when the control is not rendered?

Tags: jsf-2.2, mojarra, tomee-7

I have this on my JSF page

```
<h:link rendered="false" value="${mybean.status}" />
```

The control is not rendered but it still calls `getStatus()` method in `mybean`. Why?

The problem seems to be only with `value` attribute because If I include `href="${mybean.url}"` then `getUrl()` method does not get called.

I'm using TomEE 7.04 plume which comes with Mojarra 2.2.12.

Comment: What happens if you use `rendered="#{false}"` ?

Comment: I've tried that, no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/link.html) says about the `rendered` attribute:

> Flag indicating whether or not this component should be rendered (during Render Response Phase), or processed on any subsequent form submit.

It means that the `rendered` attribute is processed in the last lifecycle phase (`Render Response Phase`) while the value of the component was set during the `Update model values Phase`. In case of a fresh (GET) request, it is being set also in the `Render Response Phase` but clearly prior to checking the `rendered` attribute. And setting the component's value means calling the getter.

There is no `href` attribute in the `h:link` that's why no getter was called in this case.

As a workaround, you could wrap your `h:link` in `f:subview` which uses the rendered attribute in an earlier phase.

```
<f:subview rendered="false">
    <h:link rendered="false" value="${mybean.status}" />
</f:subview>
```

You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030497/when-a-form-is-handled-in-jsf-does-it-all-happen-in-one-thread), its answer and comments, there are links to the JSF lifecycle and maybe other useful information.

Comment: `href` getter does not get called if I add `href` attribute.

Comment: This is not fully correct. On an initial request for a page (in a get request), there is no form submit and no 'update model values phase' (my source for this is still always http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html btw).

Comment: @PanuHaaramo: Please read what is stated in this answer...  `h:link` has no `href` according to the docs, so it is not processed by it. Confirming what you see... You could as well add `bla="${mybean.status}"` same behaviour as `href`

Comment: I will try `f:subview`. Currently I have `<h:panelGroup rendered="false">`  around it and that does not help. I think (not absolutely sure) that the `panelGroup` solution worked previously when I used Tomcat 8 + Mojarra.

Comment: @Kukeltje You are right, but the question says nothing about what kind of request causes the problem.

Comment: Ah sorry, actually I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3 and `<p:link` which has `href` attribute so I thought `h:link` has it also. I did not include PrimeFaces in the question because I was able to reproduce without it.